# Conditionally change color of files in QListView connected to QFileSystemModel

Tags: python, pyqt, qitemdelegate, qfilesystemmodel

I'm having a `QListView` with a `QFileSystemModel`. Based on a selection in a `QTreeView`, the `QListView` shows the content of the folder.
**Now I need to change the color of the filenames depending on some condition.**
The initial idea would be to iterate over the items in the QListView and set the color for each item depending on whether the condition is fulfilled. However this seems to be impossible, since the `setData()` method of `QFileSystemModel` only accepts changes to the `EditRole`, ignoring something like [see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014076/how-to-change-color-of-item-in-qlistview)]

```
self.FileModel.setData(index, QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.red), role=QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole)
```

This has also been pointed out [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/61716-Set-the-color-of-a-row-in-a-qtreeview)
and the suggestion in the latter was to subclass `QItemDelegate` for the purpose of colorizing items in the QListView.

I therefore subclassed `QStyledItemDelegate` and reimplemented its `paint()` method to show the filename in green, if the condition is fulfilled - which works fine. However it now looks kind of ugly: File icons are lost and the "mouse_over" effect is not working anymore.

While this subclassing is anyway a messy work-around, my top-level question would be

- Is there a way to colorize items in a `QListView` connected to a `QFileSystemModel` based on a condition?

Now provided that this might not be the case and sticking to the subclassing of QItemDelegate,

- Is there a way to get the original behaviour with nice selections and icons back?
- Does anyone know which ItemDelegate is originally used for QFileSystemModel in a QListView and how to use it?
- Is it possible to get its source code and copy the paint method from there ?

Here is a minimal code that uses subclassing and shows the descibed behaviour. It uses a `QLineEdit` where one can type in a string, such that all files containing that string are highlighted in green.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class MyFileViewDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate ):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent, *args)

        self.condition = None
        self.isMatch = False

        self.brush_active =         QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("#79b9ed"))
        self.brush_active_matched = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("#58cd1c"))
        self.pen =                  QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("#414141") )
        self.pen_matched =          QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("#39c819") )
        self.pen_active =           QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("#eef2fd") )
        self.pen_active_matched =   QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("#e7fade") )


    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        text = index.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        self.matchText(text)

        painter.save()
        ######## set background 
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen))
        if option.state & QtGui.QStyle.State_Selected:
            if self.isMatch:
                painter.setBrush(self.brush_active_matched)
            else:
                painter.setBrush(self.brush_active)

        painter.drawRect(option.rect)
        ######## set font color
        if option.state & QtGui.QStyle.State_Selected:
            if self.isMatch:
                painter.setPen(self.pen_active_matched)
            else:
                painter.setPen(self.pen_active)
        else:
            if self.isMatch:
                painter.setPen(self.pen_matched) 
            else:
                painter.setPen(self.pen) 

        painter.drawText(option.rect, QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft, text)

        painter.restore()

    def matchText(self, filename):
        # testing condition. In the real case this is much more complicated
        if (self.condition != None) and (self.condition != "") and (self.condition in filename):
            self.isMatch = True
        else:
            self.isMatch = False

    def setCondition(self, condition):
        self.condition = condition


class MainWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, useDelegate = False):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())

        self.FolderModel = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
        self.FolderModel.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QtCore.QDir.AllDirs)
        self.FolderModel.setRootPath("")

        self.FolderView = QtGui.QTreeView(parent=self)
        self.FolderView.setModel(self.FolderModel)

        self.FolderView.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.FolderView.hideColumn(1)
        self.FolderView.hideColumn(2)
        self.FolderView.hideColumn(3)
        self.FolderView.expanded.connect(self.FolderView.scrollTo)
        self.FolderView.clicked[QtCore.QModelIndex].connect(self.browserClicked)

        self.FileModel = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
        self.FileModel.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QtCore.QDir.Files)

        self.FileView = QtGui.QListView(parent=self)
        self.FileView.setModel(self.FileModel)

        self.FileViewDelegate = None
        if useDelegate:
            self.FileViewDelegate = MyFileViewDelegate()
            self.FileView.setItemDelegate(self.FileViewDelegate)

        self.FileView.setSelectionMode(  QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection  ) 

        self.LineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.LineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.changeCondition)

        # Add Widgets to layout
        self.layout().addWidget(self.FolderView)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.FileView)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.LineEdit)

    def changeCondition(self, text):
        if self.FileViewDelegate:
            self.FileViewDelegate.setCondition(text)

    def browserClicked(self, index):
        # the signal passes the index of the clicked item
        # set the FileView's root_index to the clicked index
        dir_path =  self.FileModel.filePath(index) 
        root_index = self.FileModel.setRootPath(dir_path)
        self.FileView.setRootIndex(root_index)


class App(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, useDelegate=False):
        super(App, self).__init__(parent)
        self.central = MainWidget(parent =self, useDelegate=useDelegate)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    thisapp = App(None, True) # set False to view App without custom FileViewDelegate
    thisapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is the comparison of how it looks with and without subclassing QItemDelegate:

[image]

just to mention, another problem with this code is, that once the condition is changed, one needs to move the mouse into the QFileView to initiate the repainting. I wonder which slot I could use to connect to the `LineEdit.textChange` signal to do that directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need for an item-delegate. It can be achieved much more simply by reimplementing the `data` method of the `QFileSystemModel`:

```
class FileSystemModel(QtGui.QFileSystemModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FileSystemModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.condition = None

    def setCondition(self, condition):
        self.condition = condition
        self.dataChanged.emit(QtCore.QModelIndex(), QtCore.QModelIndex())

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if self.condition and role == QtCore.Qt.TextColorRole:
            text = index.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            if self.condition in text:
                return QtGui.QColor("#58cd1c")
        return super(FileSystemModel, self).data(index, role)

class MainWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, useDelegate = False):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        ...
        self.FileModel = FileSystemModel(self)
        ...

    def changeCondition(self, text):
        self.FileModel.setCondition(text)
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I wonder why I could not find this kind of subclassing of the model when looking for a solution. Is this commonly not done, or does it have any drawbacks?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Qt seems not to follow Python's [TOOWTDI](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TOOWTDI) approach - it often offers several different ways to solve certain problems. Subclassing is probably the most commonly used approach, but it obviously depends on whether the methods of interest can be usefully reimplemented (i.e. whether they're virtual methods).